# Stable commutator length of elements in free groups. 

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups

http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0611889v4.pdf   (page 13)

In the above paper by Danny Calegari he says that the result $\text{scl}(g) \geq 1/2$ (i.e. a stable commutator length $\text{scl}(g) := \displaystyle{\lim_n}\ cl(g^n) / n$, where $\text{cl}(g)$ is the smallest $k$ such that $g$ is a product of $k$ commutators) follows (apart from the Howie-Duncan result) from the paper by Comerford-Edmunds.

"Products of commutators and products of squares in a free group" by Leo P. Comerford , Jr. , Charles C. Edmunds, 1994.

Although I am familiar with that paper, I do not immediately see how that result follows from the description of solutions of quadratic equations described in Comerford&Edmunds.

Here is a reference to the paper:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.233.9038

Could anyone clarify the link between the two results?

thanks!

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you would define notation which is not standard, like ${\rm scl}(g)$. Also I think adding a little more details would be in order.
 

Comment: @Stefan: you're right. $scl(g)=\lim cl(g^n)/n$ where $cl(g)$ is the smallest $k$ such that $g$ is a product of $k$ commutators. The quantification "for all nontrivial $g$ in the derived subgroup of a free group" is probably the other missing part. Anyway, even if I'm correct, the post should be edited accordingly.

Comment: I think that $\text{scl}(g)$ (for "stable commutator length of $g$) is pretty standard at this point.

Comment: Andy: I think it depends on the subfield of the group theory. It is standard for people in geometric group theory, but not otherwise. 

Comment: ok. I've made some changes to the question. thanks.

Comment: Actually, it is more likely that Calegari was referring to this paper (..at least judging by the title of the paper it looks like that!)

J. A. Comerford, L. P. Comerford, Jr., and C. C. Edmunds, “Powers as product of commutators,”Comm. Alg.,19, No. 2, 675–684 (1991).